# How to get a response page after submit on csharp?

Tags: c#, post, web, submit, response

There is a page in remote web-site, where one can enter input values in forms, click a button and get a result in output form.
I want to send a request to the page with filling necessary input forms, submit it and get a result page with output form filled.

All threads with similar topics give the code samples like this:

```
// Create a request using a URL that can receive a post. 
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://www.site.com");
            // Set the Method property of the request to POST.
            request.Method = "POST";
            // Create POST data and convert it to a byte array.
            string postData = string.Format("inputParam=value");
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
            // Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            // Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.
            request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
            // Get the request stream.
            Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            // Write the data to the request stream.
            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            // Close the Stream object.
            dataStream.Close();
            // Get the response.
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
            dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();

            response.Close();
```

It returns a page with filled input forms, but output field is still blank, like it doesn't do a commit button click.

How can I do a commit from my C# code and receive an html document with output data?

Answer (score 0):

Change the webresponse section to the following;

```
    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse ();                
    dataStream = response.GetResponseStream ();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader (dataStream);
    string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd ();
```

Comment: OK, then I just have a string from the stream. But the problem is that the response doesn't contain output data.

Comment: what is the expected response?

Comment: There is a site URL: "http://babelfish.yahoo.com/translate_txt". Example parameters are: "lp=en_it&trtext=sea". In the response page the element with name="p" must have value="mare", but it is blank.